# What is non-trivial way of finding solution in systems of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: from a 'mathematics for ML']

Hi!

I think I understood till (2.40) but i don't seem to understand
where the 0 = 8c1 + 2c2 - 1c3 + 0c4 came from.. where did this -1 and 0 is from?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should have been asked on [math.se].

Answer (score 0):

In general these types of questions are probably better suited for https://math.stackexchange.com/ but since I like math and linear algebra I'll also answer your question.

The system of equations that you have has 4 variables and only 2 equations, so this means that you're going to have more than one solution and actually an infinite number of solutions. Not just anything will work though, so let's find what the solutions look like.

To simplify writing this let's call the 2x4 matrix `A` and the right hand side `b=(42,8)T` so what we are trying to solve is `Ax = b`. Also to write the zero vector `(0,0)T` I'll use `⍬` to save typing.

They first find a **particular solution** (some `xp` such that `Axp = b`) they do this with the first 2 columns and 0's for the other columns: `xp = (42,8,0,0)T` and when we plug this in we do get `Axp = (42,8)T`. Next they are trying to find the other solutions.

Notice that if we can find an `x0` such that `Ax0 = ⍬` then we can add this to our `xp` and it'll still be a solution: `A(xp + x0) = Axp + Ax0 = b + ⍬ = b`. So let's see if we can find an `x0`.

They do this in (2.40) by basically saying the 3rd and 4th column are not used in `xp` so let's see if we can make them 0 using the first two columns. Really we're looking for anything that'll give `Ax0=⍬` and this is just an idea how we might find that.

Now notice that the 3rd column `(8,2)T` can be written as 8 times first column + 2 times second column. So if we do **8 first column + 2 second column - 1 times third column (+ zero times forth column) we get zero**. This is just `x0 = (8,2,-1,0)T` because if we do `Ax0 = A(8,2,-1,0)T = ⍬`. Similarly we can find another one of these by using the forth column to get `(-4,12,0,-1)T` as another independent vector which I'll call `x02` because I can't think of a better notation at the moment. Both of these satisfy `Ax0 = ⍬`,  `Ax02 = ⍬`.

To make this really concrete you can see that computing `A(xp+x0) = A(50,10,-1,0)T` really does give you `(42,8)T`.

So we can add either or both to our original `xp` and it'll still be a solution that gives us the `b` we're looking for. `A(xp + x0 + x02) = Axp + Ax0 + Ax02 = b + ⍬ + ⍬ = b` Also any multiple of these `x0` or `x02` will work as well because for example `A(3*x0) = 3*Ax0 = 3*⍬ = ⍬`.

So really `A(xp + c*x0 + d*x02) = Axp + c*Ax0 + d*Ax02 = b + c*⍬ + d*⍬ = b` which means that any vector of the form `xp + c*x0 + d*x02` where `c` and `d` are any numbers (scalars) will be a solution. This is our solution set and is what the last part (2.43) is saying.